Join fetch alias on Hibernate
I am migrating from Wildfly 10.0.0 to Wildfly 34.0.1, and then Hibernate is going from version 5.0.7 to 6.2.1.
I am having following error: "Error interpreting query [The JPA specification does not permit specifying an alias for fetch joins.]".
I have found that JPA specification does not allow alias on fetch joins, but Hibernate was allowing it. For some reason they also decided to not allow it anymore in Hibernate.
The issue is that my system has a lot of queries written using it. As this example:


select distinct p
from Product p
inner join fetch p.productCharacteristicProduct pcp
inner join fetch pcp.productCharacteristic pc
where p.id in (:listProductIds)
and p.status = :statusActive
and pc.status = :statusActive



I know that I can change it and use other strategies to remove the aliases. But I would need to change a lot of queries and test all of them again. At this moment it is not an option.
I am trying to find alternatives to it. I have following alternatives/questions:
1 - is there a way to make Hibernate to accept again the aliases?
2 - can I use an old Hibernate version on Wildfly 34? How can I configure it? What is the last Hibernate version allowing aliases?
3 - it seems that EclipseLink allows it. Would Hibernate queries work on EclipseLink with no changes?
If option 1 is not possible, I would prefer option 2 as I would have some time to change old queries until I can upgrade Hibernate version.
I don't like option 3 as there is the risk that EclipseLink works a little different with queries, and no guarantee that they will continue allowing aliases on future.
Is there some other solution for it?

I don't believe EclipseLink allows it either - JPA was pretty set on filters not being able to manipulate the data for entities, as it would mess with caching these partially built entities (especially over 1:M and M:M relationships). If you are upgrading wildfly, there are bound to be a whole lot of changes - this might be the right time to fix your queries too (sorry)

May be with hibernate.jpa.compliance.query=false
